# How to create a Flux from a function that converts a state into a value and a new state?

Tags: project-reactor

I have a function that takes a `State` and produces a new `State` and a `Value`.

How do I create a Flux from that?

Or to speak code:

```
Function<State, Pair<State, Value> f = ...;

Flux<Value> values = xxx(f);
```

What is `xxx`?

Answer (score 0):

I learned, that you can do what I want easily with [`Flux.generate`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#generate-java.util.concurrent.Callable-java.util.function.BiFunction-):

```
Flux.generate(
    () -> initialState, 
    (state, sink) -> {
        Pair<State, Value> p = f.apply(state); // get the new state and the value
        sink.next(p.right); // this is basically calling the subscriber with the value
        return p.left; // this returns the new state
    }
);
```